# SQL Server can't add, delete, add column?

Tags: sql-server-2016

When I run this in a single batch:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD FOO int NULL;

alter table SomeTable drop column foo

ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD FOO int NULL;

select top 1 FOO from SomeTable
```

... why in SQL Management studio is the end result that column FOO does not exist on table SomeTable?

The select statement gives an error, but no statement previous raises an error.

Adding GO statements would fix the issue, but why in a single batch does it act as it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"why in SQL Management studio is the end result that column FOO does not exist on table SomeTable?"* It isn't. The problem is you are trying to reference a column in the same batch you performed an `ALTER` on the table you added it to; this results in the parsing error and the entire batch is not run.

Either split the `SELECT` into a separate batch (use `GO` in SSMS), or defer the parsing of the `SELECT`:

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 1 FOO FROM dbo.SomeTable ORDER BY SomeColumn;';
```

Comment: I know a GO statement  would fix it. I can add a column and an index in a single batch without error. Is the issue that I'm selecting from the newly added column in the same batch? What can/can't I do in the same batch to a newly created column?

Comment: Because of the reason I state in the answer, @DeveloperWebs: *"this results in the parsing error and the entire batch is not run."*.

Comment: Right, but I can create a new column and add an index to it in the same batch. What else can I do in a single batch to a newly created column? What about indices, if I create one does it automatically take affect in the same batch?

Comment: Because that's the way parser is set up, @DeveloperWebs ; that would be a question for the designer of SQL Server itself and probably predates it (and goes back to SyBase). That doesn't change the answer though, I am afraid. Defer the validation of the statement, or use batches.

Comment: I get that the parser is set up that way. you're missing my point. Do I *always* need Go after I add a column? What other statements can I use that affect the newly created column in the same batch without getting a parse error (adding indices to the new column in the same batch seems to not give error)? is it just wise to use GO every time you add a new column and want to use that new column in any statement?

Comment: *"Do I always need Go after I add a column?"* No, if you aren't going to reference it you don't need to. What you're asking here, however, are very different questions that should be on [dba.se].

Comment: I meant should I always use GO *IF* I'm going to reference the new column. It seems I can create a new column and then add an index to  the new column in the same batch without a parse error (it creates the column and creates the index).